# How to derive derivative from taking a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

In a book I'm reading (Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop, Appendix D), it says we can arrive at the form of $\partial y/\partial x$ of a function by writing it as:

$$
y(x+\epsilon) = y(x) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)
$$

and take limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

How is this actually done? My attempt is:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} y(x+\epsilon) &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \Big( y(x) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2) \Big) \\
y(x) &= y(x) + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2) \Big) \\
0 &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2) \Big) \\
\end{align}
$$

And I'm not sure what to do next...

Comment: $$y(x + \epsilon) = y(x) + \partial_{x} y \cdot \epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2}) \implies \frac{y(x + \epsilon) - y(x)}{\epsilon} = \partial_{x} y + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$$ _then_ take the limit.

Comment: The derivative is related to litle "o" notation. Not to Big "O" notation. See [Wikipedia to definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).